# input foreach is not a function

Tags: javascript, foreach

The below is returning '**input for each is not a function**' in the console, and I cannot figure out why. No syntax issues are being reported.

```
let inputs = {"cooluser":{"userAchkData":[{"id":"slz1","checked":false},{"id":"slz2","checked":false},{"id":"slz3","checked":false},{"id":"slz4","checked":false},{"id":"slz5","checked":false},{"id":"slz6","checked":false},{"id":"slz7","checked":false},{"id":"slz8","checked":false},{"id":"slz9","checked":false},{"id":"slz10","checked":false},{"id":"slz11","checked":false},{"id":"slz12","checked":false},{"id":"slz13","checked":false},{"id":"slz14","checked":true},{"id":"slz15","checked":false},{"id":"slz16","checked":false},{"id":"slz17","checked":false},{"id":"slz18","checked":false},{"id":"slz19","checked":false},{"id":"slz20","checked":false},{"id":"slz21","checked":false},{"id":"slz22","checked":false},{"id":"slz23","checked":false},{"id":"slz24","checked":false},{"id":"slz25","checked":false},{"id":"slz26","checked":false},{"id":"slz27","checked":false},{"id":"slz28","checked":false},{"id":"slz29","checked":false},{"id":"slz30","checked":false}]}}

                    inputs.forEach(function (input) {
                        if (input.id == 'slz14' && input.checked) { 
                            console.log("blahblah");
                            console.log(input.id + " " + input.checked);
                            var inputslz14 = document.getElementById(input.id);
                            inputslz14.id.click();

                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Because [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is an array method.

Comment: `inputs` is an object and it doesn't have this method. Why do you think it would?

Comment: I have not thought that far but it would be nice to have a forEach(value,key) on object like it is for Map @VLAZ

Comment: @grodzi `Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {})`

Comment: yeah it works, but it's like Object.keys(obj)... that's a bit so-so isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `inputs` is basically a object and object doesn't have `forEach`. It exists of `Array.prototype`. Seems that you want to iterate which is nested two levels down in the object.

```
inputs.cooluser.userAchkData.forEach(function(input) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be repeating its children like below. You can't access id by repeating your inputs, go deeper to `userAchkData`

```js
let inputs = {
  "cooluser": {
    "userAchkData": [{
      "id": "slz1",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz2",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz3",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz4",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz5",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz6",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz7",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz8",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz9",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz10",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz11",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz12",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz13",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz14",
      "checked": true
    }, {
      "id": "slz15",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz16",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz17",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz18",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz19",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz20",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz21",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz22",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz23",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz24",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz25",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz26",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz27",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz28",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz29",
      "checked": false
    }, {
      "id": "slz30",
      "checked": false
    }]
  }
}

inputs.cooluser.userAchkData.forEach(function(input) {
  if (input.id == 'slz14' && input.checked) {
    console.log("blahblah");
    console.log(input.id + " " + input.checked);
    var inputslz14 = document.getElementById(input.id);
    inputslz14.id.click();

  }
});
```